Prove that the limits of these two recurring sequences is pi.
I'm trying to prove that these two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge to $\pi$, but cannot find a method of doing so. The two sequences are defined as such:
$a_0=2\sqrt3, b_0=3$
$a_n= \frac{2a_{n-1}b_{n-1}}{a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}}$
$b_n=\sqrt{a_n b_{n-1}}$
So far, I have proved that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, a_n>b_n$, that, if the limits of both exist, they are equal, and that $a_n$ is decreasing and $b_n$ is increasing, but I am utterly stuck at how I should prove that this limit is in fact $\pi$. I have tried playing with the definition of convergence, but still am stuck!
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Just to be absolutely certain that it's not a typo: you sure it isn't $b_n=\sqrt{a_{n-1}b_{n-1}}$ instead?

@Arthur Absolutely certain!

In fact, this is a very famous algorithm of computing $\pi$, known as LiuHui-Archimedes algorithm. You can show that $a_n$ is the half-perimeter of a regular $6\times 2^n$-sided polygon which is tangent to a unit circle, while $b_n$ is the half-perimeter of a regular $6\times 2^n$-sided polygon which is inscribed to a unit circle.
More specifically, we can use induction to show that
$$a_n=6\times 2^{n}\tan\frac{\pi}{6\times 2^n},b_n=6\times 2^{n}\sin\frac{\pi}{6\times 2^n}$$
This is a very simple calculation of trigonometric functions.
Then it is obviously that $a_n,b_n$ converge to $\pi$.

I think the textbook I am using somehow expects me to just know this, despite it being a real analysis book for (presumably) undergraduates. It gave no indication as to this algorithm, nor its geometric connections! If I were to be a maths student who didn't know this "very famous" result, how on earth would I find this out? (other than posting here or asking my professor)

I agree with you. If we do not know this algorithm in advance, it may be very hard to think of this. A far-fetched explanation is that if you want the limit $\pi$, algebraic expression may be useless, since it is very hard for $\pi$ to come from them. So an alternative is to consider trigonometric functions. Since the our aim is $\pi$, we may expect a form $n\sin \frac{\pi}{n}$. You may come up with the right formula after some tries. Anyway, you cannot expect every problem to have a natural solution.

I calculated the first few values of $a_n$ manually, getting 2sqrt3 (as given), then 12(2-sqrt(3)), etc. Theoretically, I could stumble across tan(pi/6)=sqrt(3)/3, then 32tan(pi/3*2) = 2sqrt3. After that, I could see that it holds for $a_2$, etc... But that's quite far reaching to assume that I'd find that needle in the haystack. Thank you for this insight, I genuinely don't think I could have completed this w/o your answer!
